# Button for remove a object in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, mongodb

Sorry for my bad english. 
I have a problem. I need to create, for all object in my mongoDB, a delete button for each object.

I use mongodb, Nodejs, ajax and jquery.

This is my mongodb code :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ce990ac4e8ec94124a1c2c"),
    "Pseudo" : "shade",
    "Commentaire" : "blabla",
    "Note" : "2",
    "Date" : ISODate("2016-09-06T10:22:53.257Z")
 }
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("57cebf1c12253ee41e0aa53e"),
    "Pseudo" : "shade2",
    "Commentaire" : "blablaalalalallala",
    "Note" : "5",
    "Date" : ISODate("2016-09-06T13:00:10.871Z")
 }
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("57d7b7b909087b981124bc42"),
    "Pseudo" : "shade3",
    "Commentaire" : "hfsduhfdiugfusqdigfqgfugsufgsfqd",
    "Note" : "1",
    "Date" : ISODate("2016-09-13T07:45:24.970Z")
 }
```

My node code :

```
 var express = require('express');
 var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
 var app = express();
 var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
 var url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/jeux';
 var myDate = new Date;
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/fichiers'));
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
     extended: true
 }));
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/fichiers'))

 app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 res.render('index.html');
 })

 app.get('/api/affiche', function (req,res){
 MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connection established to', url);

        db.collection('temp').find().toArray(function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            } else {
                res.json(result);        
            }
        });
    }
});
})

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
var adressHost = server.address().address;
var portHost = server.address().port;
console.log('Ecoute à l\'adresse http://%s:%s', adressHost, portHost);
});
```

My jade code

```
    doctype html(lang='fr')
head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    script(type='text/javascript', src='jquery.js')
    script(type='text/javascript', src='admin.js')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='admin.css')
body
    h1 Page d'admin
    .listeAvis
```

And my jquery/ajax code

```
$(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/affiche',
    success: function (data) {
        $('.liste').html('<h2>Nouveaux avis</h2>');
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            //var i = 0;
            $('.listeAvis').append('<p>pseudo : ' + data[i].Pseudo + '</p>');
            $('.listeAvis').append('<p>commentaire : ' + data[i].Commentaire + '</p>');
            $('.listeAvis').append('<p>note : ' + data[i].Note + '</p>');
            $('.listeAvis').append('<p>-----------------------------</p>');
            $('.listeAvis').append('<br></br>');

        }
    }
})
})
```

I thought but I can not find how to do. Please help me :(

Comment: Welcome to SO. Although your post is quite well documented, you don't provide a lot of info on your actual problem. What exactly is not working, where does it fail and do you get any error message ?

Comment: My problem is : I don't know how to create a delete button for each object. I have not coded that because I do not know how to do it. 
The only thing I did was show the database on my html / jade. But I want a button to remove the object that I want to delete.

Comment: Sorry but Then your question is actually not suited for SO. You would need to at least show us you tried, because novody here is supposed to write code from scratch for you.

Comment: hi Tony, i agree with Laurent. you should do some research from your end and if you have trouble somebody can help but complete code from scratch is not possible. However i can give you some hints so that you can start working on it. define a button and on click of that implement logic for findAndRemove(query, sort, options, callback).  look out for collections related methods for mongo nodejs driver. you will find it